# How to distinguish between normal and test calls

Tags: django-rest-framework

I've written unit test cases which calls the views & serializers.  How can Serializer or View identify if the incoming call is a genuine one or a test call?

Kindly let me know and thanks

Comment: Why do you need to know? Your code shouldn’t behave differently, otherwise the test is somewhat moot.

Comment: Thanks for reverting.  I want to know because, in real time I will make some uploads to cloud which I can by-pass for tests

Comment: For that you should configure something in settings.py, like an upload class or credentials or something that can be switched in tests. Preferably you *mock* the class responsible for uploading to have as little if..else in your code as possible.